# Enabling journaling on SQL Service Broker

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to enable journaling on SSB, I tried to find any information but so far I could not find anything.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Journaling*".

Comment: A copy of the processed messages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx#bdadotnetasync2_topic4. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

"here is no real concept of tracking, journaling, or auditing built into to Service Broker."

http://zachbonham.blogspot.ie/2008/08/service-broker-as-queuing-technology.html

All said.